# emberjs split promise array

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to split an ember store record into 3 columns for display purposes.  I am attempting to do this in a controller action but I have a feeling this is wrong due to the way promises are filled.

Gist of how I would like my data to look (handlebar friendly).

```
var events = [
  {column: ['work1','work2','work3']}, 
  {column: ['priv1','priv2','priv3']}, 
  {column: ['mail1','mail2','mail3']}
];
```

Below is the code I am running.  When I attempt to arrange the events into a different object no data is stored.

```
//app/controllers/index.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    columns: function(){
        var events = this.store.find('event');
        var columns = [[],[],[]];
        var count = 0;
        events.forEach(function(item, index, enumerable){
            columns[count].push(item);
            count++;
            if (count === 4){
              count = 0;
            }
        });
        columns = [{column: columns[0]}, {column: columns[1]}, {column: columns[2]}];
        return columns;
    }.property()
});
```

.

```
//app/templates/index.hbs
<div class="row">
  {{#each 'columns'}}
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      {{#each 'column'}}
        {{this}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns a promise, so you need to wait for it to resolve before you can use it.  Additionally you should use `pushObject` so that Ember is aware you've added a new item to the array.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    columns:[[],[],[]],
    setupColumns: function(){
        var eventsPromise = this.store.find('event'),
            columns = [[],[],[]],
            count = 0,
            self = this;
        eventsPromise.then(function(events){
          events.forEach(function(item, index, enumerable){
            columns[count].pushObject(item);
            count++;
            if (count === 4){
              count = 0;
            }
          });
          self.set('columns', [{column: columns[0]}, {column: columns[1]}, {column: columns[2]}]);
        });
    }.on('init')
});
```

Honestly you should resolve the model before the controller (in the route), it would make this significantly easier.

Comment: Should I be interacting with the eventPromise any differently if I resolve the model in the route?  I've done this and it works fine with the code above but I wasn't sure if there is a better way.  Thanks!

Comment: are you returning it from the model hook?  How are you using?

Comment: I think I figured it out.   I loaded the model in the route then I used `var events = this.get('model');`  to build my columns array.

Comment: yeah, if you resolve it in the route, you can switch back to it being a computed property, which feels cleaner to me.